# Cygwin's Ruby malfunctions

Tags: ruby, cygwin

I'm trying to develop in Ruby under a windows environment using cygwin.
So far, in order to get ruby working, I tried installing it via rvm which ended up with compilation errors. So I tried installing directly the Ruby version cygwin's installer provides with a fresh install of cygwin, adding only Ruby and the silver-searcher to the default package set.

```
ruby -v
```

Cygwin "freezes" like it's busy doing something and ends up outputing nothing. By the way, It does exactly the same thing with silver-searcher which usually functions as intended... I didn't import any custom dotfiles to be sure my dotfiles were not messing with this Ruby install.
Any clues on how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct output should be

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.2.5p319 (2016-04-26 revision 54774) [x86_64-cygwin]
```

2 main possibilities:

> 1st the installation is broken, so run `cygcheck -c` and check if something is missing and reinstall the broken packages.
>
> 2nd (more likely) a third party software, usually an antivirus, is interfering. See
>   https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda for details.

You can also follows the guideline at https://cygwin.com/problems.html and ask help on the cygwin general mailing list (https://cygwin.com/lists.html) providing there the requested `cygcheck.out`

Comment: I agree with you on the antivirus part, unfortunately I can't deactivate it, so I'll have to find an other way to do what I want to do...

Comment: then open a bug request to the Antivirus company.